# Resource response style in express js with API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, express

I'm a nob in `expressjs` and just using it so I have this response in my controller

```
....
res.json({
    'data': {
        'user': {
            'id': user.id,
            'name': user.name,
            'email': user.email,
        },
        'token': token
    }
});
```

In Laravel, there is something called [`eloquent-resources`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources)  that takes the data of something and puts it in a separate class, and arranges this data as you need!

IS there any thing like this in express js

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent is ORM for just Laravel. This is strongly connected with your application. There are many ORMs for express.js but most known is [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/). It supports MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. It does have Model structure and you can use sequelize models for your responses.

```
    const User = sequelize.define('User', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
  firstName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
    // allowNull defaults to true
  }
}, {
  // Other model options go here
});
```

Like this and after that you can use your Model like a normal object and return it inside your response.